# Erro ao atualizar modelo através do banco de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá,

deletei no sql server uma tabela, no visual studio 2015 fui atualizar a opção "update model from database", atualizou minha mudança. Porém ao salvar o EDMX todas as entidades(tabelas) do EDMX sumiram, como se tivesse deletado todas elas. No Team Explorer mostra como se eu tivesse deletado todas.

Se eu utilizar a opção "undo changes" elas voltam ao EDMX, porém

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou fechar o VS e abrir de novo (EDMX é meio bugado)

Answer (score 1):

Já tive um bug parecido.

Minha solução foi a seguinte, apagar as tabelas do edmx, salvar e após isso ao invés de dar um "update", ir e adicionar como novas todas as entidades novamente.